# C# Combobox SelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: c#, .net

Ok, i have a problem, I need several text boxes to fill up with data after I select different values from the comboBox and I need an event to do it, but this isn't working for some reason:

```
private override void rasaCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I've tested it and it seems it doesn't even recognize this as a valid event, since it never enters that part of the code. I'm using Visual C# 2010. Help?

Comment: The combobox doesn't have an event attached by default. An event must be added to it first.

Comment: How did you generate that method?  Simply double-clicking on the `ComboBox` in the `Form` designer will generate and hook-up the method for you.  I suspect, due to the presence of the `override` keyword that you wrote this yourself?

Comment: Ah, the override stood there because I was trying something else. Never occurred to me that I simply need to double click it to add the event, I'm kinda new to C#. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem.  Guess I should have made that an answer.  Note that double-clicking a control defaults to the most common event handler.  To add others you need to access them in the VS Properties window.

Answer (score 2):

No override needed

```
private void rasaCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Check if you suscribe to event somewhere.

```
rasaCombo_.SelectedIndexChanged += rasaCombo_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem was that I didn't double click the combo box to add the event. Beginner's mistake. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @user1481171 well you don't NEED to double click, it's just write the += code for you. But you can also do that manually ;)

Answer (score -1):

why are you overriding the eventhandler? I don't think you need it.

Comment: Dude, its a copy paste error!! u caught me before I edited.....man you guys are fast?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't have known that when I voted. I still don't think this is a good answer, but I'll take off the -1 (edit: it won't let me unless you edit the question...)